# How to use While loop in R to read the name of the heading to correlate accordingly

Tags: r, correlation

I have 2 excel files on eating habit of a population, file A (year 1997) and file B (year 2000).

I've imported them into R. 
File A has 35 headings, each with 200 data.
File B has 35 headings, each with 200 data.

How do I do a while loop to correlate:

heading 1 from file A with heading 1 from file B, and so on?
The heading is in letters, so I figured maybe I can use ncol, by asking the computer to use column 1 in file A to correlate with column 1 in file B.

Any advise is really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: do both files have the same identical headings?

Comment: [Please include sample data and code you've tried.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Another good ref: [MWEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if both files have same column and in same order then you can simply use `rbind`.

Comment: @Stephan Yes sir both files have same heading: Apple, Orange, Grapes etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order of columns are same (as OP has indicated) in both dataframes then one approach could be to rename both with consistent name. And then use `rbind`.

In the below code, columns names are changed to `V1`, `V2` ... `V35` for both dataframes. Afterwards they will automatically correlate and merged using `rbind`.

```
names(A) <- paste("V",1:35,sep="")
names(B) <- paste("V",1:35,sep="")

rbind(A, B)
```

**UPDATED**

Since OP wants keep the names of dataframe, then best option could be to rename the one dataframe with column names from other.

```
names(B) <- names(A)
```

Now both dataframes will have same column names.

Comment: renaming the columns to V1,V2 etc sounds good, but it would be difficult for me to remember the original headings if I wanted to refer back later

Comment: @MT32 You can just renamed them with consistent names of your choice as `names(A) <- c("col1", "col2","col3")`. Or simply you can rename columns of `B` as columns of `A`.